# Deploying to testnet using Truffle and Metamask

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, testnets, metamask

Is it possible to deploy a smart contract developed using truffle to testnet using just Metamask (without a local eth client instance running)?

I tried importing the private key of metamask wallet to my local geth instance, but the balance still shows zero.

Any pointers on how to deploy a smart contract to testnet?

Comment: For you ethereum client is ethereum wallet for example?

Comment: Yes, either a wallet or a client is ok. A wallet does internally use a client. My Mist wallet hasn't completed syncing for ages, hence I tried directly from geth

Comment: I think's you don't need use the wallet if you are using metamask, i'm doing the same with meteor.js and i don't need have opened or runned the wallet. For change the network you can use metamask in the left corner you can choose it.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what testnet you want to deploy to you can use a custom provider. Follow this link [truffleframework.com/tutorials/using-infura-custom-provider](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/using-infura-custom-provider).