# How to deploy smart contract using truffle , metamask with ropsten network

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, metamask, ropsten

This question is an extension of [Deploying to testnet using Truffle and Metamask](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16276/deploying-to-testnet-using-truffle-and-metamask)

Need to deploy smart contracts over ropsten testnet that connected through metamask . I am using truffle framework to write smart contract so what should i write in truffle.js to achieve the task.

Comment: I just answered this post which should give you all you need: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/23320/4108

Comment: i follow your answer , i use second method but it gives me error - (node:23567) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: this.provider.sendAsync is not a function
how do i resolve it

Comment: Hi, Sorry I forgot one point. The answer is update for more details. But inn short, you need to `run npm init` and then `npm install ethereumjs-wallet bip39 web3-provider-engine web3@0.19.0 --save`

Comment: @GregJeanmart i already do that but same problem occurs

Comment: It's working correctly for me. I copied my **package.json** [here](https://gist.github.com/gjeanmart/2193891b3dbf73207c084ce782d39494) so you can have a look and maybe remove the **node-modules** folder and rerun `npm install`